# Why is my timer showing the same value even after printing 100 digits in bash

Tags: bash

So I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

start_timer=$(date +%s)
echo $start_timer

for ((i=1;i<=100;i++));
do
    echo $i
done

end_timer=$(date +%s)
echo $end_timer
```

I wanted to time how long the loop process would take, so i initialized a start and end timer and print them out.

I notice that both start_timer and end_timer are showing the same value. Why is it so?

Comment: bash is slow, but it's not _that_ slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough precision being captured from the `date` command to show a visible difference (`%s` is an integer number of seconds), and your  code runs in under a second. To illustrate I bumped up the runtime of the code by increasing `N` to something that'll run longer than 1 second. Example below, note I used the modulus (`%`) operator to illustrate progress:

```
start_timer=$(date +%s)
echo $start_timer

for ((i=1;i<=1000000;i++));
do
    [[ $((i % 100000)) == 0 ]] && echo $i
done

end_timer=$(date +%s)
echo $end_timer
```

Output:

```
1610944389
100000
200000
300000
400000
500000
600000
700000
800000
900000
1000000
1610944391
```

Use `+%s%N` instead to capture nanoseconds.

Answer (score 1):

The builtin `time` command can be used to see how long things take.

```sh
time for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do echo $i; done
```

outputs

```
...
 99
100

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.000s
```